# no error on bad column filter without suffix

Tags: google-bigquery

there is no error when i launch this code bud i should have one, cause the column in T2 doesn't exist :
`with t1 as  ( select 1 as column_name union all  select 2 as column_name ) , t2 as  ( select 1 as column_name_with_suffix ) select column_name from t1 where column_name not in (select column_name from t2)`

if i change the column_name in the subquery, it works :

`with t1 as  ( select 1 as column_name union all  select 2 as column_name ) , t2 as  ( select 1 as column_name_with_suffix ) select column_name from t1 where column_name not in (select column_name_with_suffix from t2)`

the problem is in the first case, bigquery returns a table with 0 line, but it has to return an error.
thx